# Play! + Less: Global variables

Tags: playframework, less

I have one file that includes all of my imports

`my-file.less`:

```
@import "import-one";
@import "import-two";
```

I thought this would be enough to include the variables located in `"import-one"` file for my `"import-two"` file. However, I'm getting this error like this:

```
[error] assets/stylesheets/import-two.less:10 Compilation error[variable @my-var is undefined]
```

How can I define global variables without having to import that global file in each of my less files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix the two files with underscore: "_import-one" and "_import-two". This prevents them to be compiled. Take a look here how I do the same with Twitter Bootstrap:
https://github.com/RadoBuransky/jugjane/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.less